# When everyone looks bad to a bad individual

Tags: sentence-request

In my language, there is a saying which says a bad person would habitually consider everyone to him/herself just because his essenزe / nature is not clear. I have found a proverb in my dictionary of proverbs and colloquialism, but I need to get a confirmation if it works in today / modern American English or it is somehow odd to you. Meanwhile I would be thankful if you could give me some other suggestions:

> - All things look yellow to the jaundiced eye.

Comment: The word `projecting` is a way to describe this idea (but it is not a proverb).

Examples:
I am often late, so I assume others will be often late.
I don't understand the topic, so I assume others don't understand the topic.

I am projecting. I am projecting attributes of myself onto others.

Comment: From the KJ version of the Bible: To the pure, all things are pure.  But many speakers would not know the reference.

Comment: @TRomano, but I exactly want to convey the opposite message. "All things look bad to a bad person because he /she has a bad nature". This is what I need to say. :)

Comment: @A-friend: It was a backhand way of saying it. The passage goes on to say "...but unto them that are defiled and unbelieving is nothing pure; but even their mind and conscience is defiled."

Comment: Cynical works here doesn't it?

Comment: MichaelCurry I have no idea. Let's see what @TRomano would say?

Answer (score 1):

["It takes one to know one"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/it-takes-one-to-know-one)

> The person who expressed criticism has similar faults to the person being criticized.

["The pot calling the kettle black"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pot-calling-the-kettle-black--the)

> Accusing someone of faults that one has oneself...

Both quotes from the linked source, www.dictionary.com